# Why is energy released when lattice formation takes place?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

Whenever an ionic bond formation takes place it does so by forming a lattice and a subsequent amount of energy is released. What are the cause of release of energy and where does this energy come from and what is its form? 
I am really confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [Born–Landé equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_energy#Born%E2%80%93Land%C3%A9_equation) and the [Madelung constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_constant)